# Can a wrapped web page in a mobile app hide the banner that informs users of cookies?

Tags: flutter, cookies, mobile

My team is building a mobile app that has some native and some wrapped flows. When the app enters a wrapped flow, then the user sees a banner indicating if the user continues to use our site, they are also allowing cookies. It is preferable to hide that banner, however, we have a couple concerns. First, will our app be rejected my Apple/Google when submitting app to their app store? Secondly, are we becoming non-compliant for data privacy rules/laws in doing so?

Thanks!

We are also concerned that if a user is savvy enough to implement rules on their device to automatically reject all cookies, that when they enter a wrapped flow, they would be unable to successfully enter/complete flow.